# Code reads next result and loops between the two for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Even though I have set the code to only allow it to run once (done = true) until it loops through the function again, and even though I have it compare the last ones, it still loops through the two. Here's my code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ready!')
    checkLiveUpdating();
});

function checkLiveUpdating() {
    if(config.Server.AutoRefresh.Enabled == true) {
        const guild = client.guilds.get(config.Server.GuildId);
        if(guild) {
            const channel = guild.channels.find("name", config.Server.AutoRefresh.ChannelName);
        if(channel) {
            liveUpdating(channel);
        } else {
            console.log("Valid channel not found! Please check your settings and the bot's permissions.");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Guild not found! Please check the id and make sure the bot is joined to the guild.");
    }
}
}

async function liveUpdating(Channel) {
var LatestMessage = "";
while(true) {
request('https://' + config.Logger.Subdomain + "." + activitylink, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('.activity-type-edit').each(function(i, element) {
                if($("strong a", element).text().indexOf("User:") === -1 && done == false) {
                    var whatWasEdited = $("table tbody tr td em", element).text();
                    if(whatWasEdited !== "") {} else {whatWasEdited = "Page";}
                    var Message = $("strong a", element).text() + " - " + $("cite span", element).text() + ". Edited: " + whatWasEdited;
                    if(LatestMessage !== Message) {
                        Channel.send(`New edit on the wikia:\n${Message}`);
                        LatestMessage = Message;
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    await delay(1000)
    done = false;
}
}
```

And my output in #logger is:

```
    New edit on the wikia:
    Red Counter - edited by TomurA5 10 minutes ago. Edited: Added photo
    New edit on the wikia:
    Eijiro Kirishima - edited by TomurA5 12 minutes ago. Edited: Summary
```

that repeats endlessly, when I should only get:
`New edit on the wikia:
Red Counter - edited by TomurA5 10 minutes ago. Edited: Added photo`

I can't see exactly what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I changed my code:

```
async function liveUpdating(Channel) {
    var Message = "";
    while(true) {
        itemFound = false;
        request('https://' + config.Logger.Subdomain + "." + activitylink, function (error, response, html) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var list = $('div[id="list"]');
                var i = 0;
                while(itemFound == false) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    var nextItem = list.children(i);
                    if($("strong a", nextItem).text().indexOf("User:") === -1) {
                        itemFound = true;
                        var newMessage = `New Edit on the Wikia:\n${$("strong a", nextItem).text()} - ${$("cite span", nextItem).text()}`;
                        if(newMessage !== Message) {
                            Channel.send(newMessage);
                            Message = newMessage;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        await delay(1000);
    }
}
```

And now my output is this:
`New Edit on the Wikia:
 -`

Comment: It look like you've created a kind of race condition here. You don't know when `request` will get to the line `done = true` but you will set `done = false` after waiting 1 second. You should probably wrap `request` in a promise and `await` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you have `while(true)`. That will always be true, by definition, which means it will run an endless number of times.

Comment: It's supposed to go forever, but it isn't supposed to spam the same results, and there should only be one result.